# looping through an array to find euclidean distance in python

Tags: python, loops, numpy

This is what I have thus far:

```
Stats2003 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2003.txt') 
Stats2004 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2004.txt') 
Stats2005 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2005.txt') 
Stats2006 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2006.txt')
Stats2007 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2007.txt') 
Stats2008 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2008.txt')
Stats2009 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2009.txt') 
Stats2010 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2010.txt') 
Stats2011 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2011.txt') 
Stats2012 = np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/2012.txt') 

Stats = Stats2003, Stats2004, Stats2004, Stats2005, Stats2006, Stats2007, Stats2008, Stats2009, Stats2010, Stats2011, Stats2012
```

I am trying to calculate euclidean distance between each of these arrays with every other array but am having difficulty doing so.

I have the output I would like by calculating the distance like:

```
dist1 = np.linalg.norm(Stats2003-Stats2004)
dist2 = np.linalg.norm(Stats2003-Stats2005)
dist11 = np.linalg.norm(Stats2004-Stats2005)
```

etc but I would like to make these calculations with a loop.

I am displaying the calculations into a table using Prettytable.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I haven't found any previous solutions that have worked.

Comment: What's the final table look like?

Comment: The table has column headers for each year (2003,2004,etc - 2012) and row headers the same way (2003,2004, etc - 2012).  Each tuple then shows the euclidean distance between a given year and any other year.

http://cl.ly/image/07120Z171z1z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

From the documentation:

> Computes distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.

So you could do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
# start year to stop year
years = range(2003,2013)
# this will yield an n_years X n_features array
features = np.array([np.loadtxt('/Datafiles/%s.txt' % year) for year in years])
# compute the euclidean distance from each year to every other year
distance_matrix = cdist(features,features,metric = 'euclidean')
```

If you know the start year, and you aren't missing data for any years, then it's easy to determine which two years are being compared at coordinate `(m,n)` in the distance matrix.

Answer (score 2):

To do the loop you will need to [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).  A simple solution would be to use dictionaries instead.  The loops are implicit in the dict comprehensions:

```
import itertools as it

years = range(2003, 2013)
stats = {y: np.loadtxt('/DataFiles/{}.txt'.format(y) for y in years}
dists = {(y1,y2): np.linalg.norm(stats[y1] - stats[y2]) for (y1, y2) in it.combinations(years, 2)}
```

now access stats for a particular year, e.g. 2007, by `stats[2007]` and distances with tuples e.g. `dists[(2007, 20011)]`.

Comment: I made a typo in the norm, fixed now.